# How to run javaws 7u21 with java7u75?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to run an older version of javaws (7u21) by extracting it's files (javaws.jar and deploy.jar) and running it with java 7u75.

I could override the javaws.jar and deploy.jar from java7u75 and everything works as expected but I don't want to modify the jre itself.

The command that I'm running is something similar to:

```
C:\java7u75\...\javaw.exe -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\java7u21\javaws.jar;C:\java7u21\deploy.jar com.sun.javaws.Main
```

The actual problem:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:   
com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getPlatformUserHome()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Looks like getPlatformUserHome() is a native method so I need to load deploy.dll as well.

I tried appending:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\...\deploy.dll
```

but still nothing.

Is there a complete list of javaws dependencies I can load at runtime? or I really need to override those 2 files in the java installation.

Running only with java7u21 or java7u75 is not an option.

Comment: I really don't know whether it is possible to slap together parts of different JDKs. But the main question should be: Why are you doing this? I even cannot imagine a reason to do so ...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to mix two versions? The solution (if there is one) is going to be a hack of which you can never be sure if it works 100%. Solving the underlying problem (the reason why you are trying this) would be a much better solution than trying to hack this until it works. (This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I have an application that needs java 7u75 that has a jar missing the Codebase and Permissions attributes. Since that, we can't use javaws 7u75 since it's updated to block such jars

Comment: Why don't you fix the application instead of trying to hack it this way?

Comment: can't. already deployed to customers that don't want to update :)